# How to put default file extension in save as dialog using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, prompt, savefiledialog

When I clicked on `asp:button`, it will prompt a save as dialog box. But I want to put default extension.

```
 function Open() {
        // var open = document.getElementById('<%=btnGenerate.ClientID %>>').click();
        var obj = document.getElementById('<%=rbtGenerateinpage.ClientID %>');
       // var path = "C:\Users\karthik.mushyam\Downloads";
        if (obj.checked == true) {
            window.open("WebForm1.aspx", "Page", "menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, width=900, height=600");
        }   
        else {
            document.execCommand("SaveAs", true);
        }    
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I put this .default extension to be `.sql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your issue with with the "SaveAs" command, the third parameter to `execCommand` is the name of the file to be saved as in:

```
document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "myfile.sql");
```

Details are on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#saveas).